# src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor' & Cap.read()' is not reading the video frame

Tags: python, opencv

Python 3.8, Opencv 4.4.0

I have loaded correctly video file it's running, I think `Cap.read()` is not reading the video frame. I'm working on mask detection project and want to test in pre-recorded wearing mask Video.

**Full Code**

```
# import packages
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
import numpy as np

model = load_model('model_02.h5')
img_width, img_hight = 200, 200

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')  
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('wearingmask.mp4') # for video

img_count_full = 0
 
#parameters for text
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX 
org = (1, 1)
class_lable=' '      
fontScale = 1
# Blue color in BGR 
color = (255, 0, 0) 
thickness = 2 #1

while True:
    img_count_full += 1
     
    response, color_img = cap.read()
     
    if response == False:
        break       
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(color_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, 1.1, 6)
```

**FULL ERROR**

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d7656fcb48d9> in <module>
     39         break
     40 
---> 41 gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(color_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     42 faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, 1.1, 6)

error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-9d_dfo3_\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty self explanatory. Your code's core logic is basically loop through images in the video until there are no more images, and then apply `cvtColor` on the *last image*.

Your `while` loop breaks when `response` is `False`, that is, you've reached the end of your video file. However, when response is `False`, the corresponding `color_img` is actually `None`. To actually get the last valid image, you need to do something like:

```
while True:
    img_count_full += 1
     
    response, frame = cap.read()
    if response == False:
        break
    color_img = frame

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(color_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```